# "This is the one encyclopedia upon which I can depend." Can I put the proposition 【upon】 at the end of the sentence?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, formality, pied-piping

"This is the one encyclopedia upon which I can depend." Can I put the proposition 【upon】 at the end of the sentence?  That is" This is the one encyclopedia which I can depend upon."

And for the sentence " The man whom you asked about is here", whether its grammar is correct if I say " The man about whom you asked is here." ?

Comment: These are all grammatical, but they're not really colloquial English. Nobody **says** _upon_ unless they're reading or quoting. And _whom_ should be avoided, as should pied-piping; strand the preposition at the end instead. Colloquial American English would be _This is the one encyclopedia I can depend on, The man you asked about is here._

Comment: ... [following on from John's comment] Those are colloquial in the UK too.

Comment: @JohnLawler Why would you use the word 'colloquial'? The way you use it, it sounds like you mean 'natural'. As far as I know, 'colloquial' means 'conversational'. So by saying that they're all grammatical but not colloquial, you might be saying that the OP's sentences are natural if in writing, which I don't think they are. And you call your own sentences "colloquial American English", but I think they're natural in writing as well as in speech, so I don't know why you call them 'colloquial'. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Same question for you too.

Comment: Writing is not natural; it's technology. Since our writing system doesn't represent the spoken language, it has developed a congeries of unnatural styles and habits (like apostrophe's) to overcome the medieval literacy system. When I say "colloquial", I mean a way that is close to what English speakers **say**, not what they write. My only advice about writing is to write the way you talk, but learn how to speak well first.

Comment: @JK2 'Something the man in the street would find natural _in conversation_.'

Comment: As far as I know, Jamaica is the only place on Earth where the rule about not ending sentences with prepositions is followed.

Comment: @JohnLawler I use *upon* conversationally in various contexts. I might even use it in this sentence.

Comment: @JohnLawler _When I say "colloquial", I mean a way that is close to what English speakers say, not what they write._ Agreed. But English speakers not only say but also write things like _This is the one encyclopedia I can depend on_ or _The man you asked about is here_, don't they? If so, how could these be "colloquial"?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Are you saying _This is the one encyclopedia I can depend on_ or _The man you asked about is here_ is NOT something the man in the street would find natural _in writing_?

Comment: @JohnLawler I can't resist mentioning a Vietnamese coworker who consistently used *upon* in place of *on*; and he pronounced it /'ju.pɔn/.

Comment: @JK2 I've commented only on the fact that those two sentences would sound natural in everyday conversation. That seems clear to me as I re-read the earlier comments I made.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The way JohnLawler and you have used the term 'colloquial' might suggest that the OP's sentences are lacking in some aspect just because it's not 'colloquial'. Note that the OP hasn't specifically asked if those sentences could be used in conversation.

Comment: @JK2 Some judgement call has to be made in answering "Can I put ...?" questions. You can 'put' 'Colorless green ideas sleep furiously.' (Chomsky famously did.) It's grammatical ... but breaks Orwell's Sixth Rule ('Don't idly use anything outlandish'). You can 'put' _curiouser and curiouser_, while 'curiouser' itself is ill-formed. You can 'put' _The cat on sat the yellow_. Or worse gibberish. John and I have sought to answer the question in the way we consider the most helpful. Addinsonian terminations per se have already been covered many times on ELU. A clinical 'Yes' would be off-topic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think you clearly understood my point. But apparently, you don't want to address it. So be it.

Comment: @JK2 If my comment still leaves your point unaddressed, I've got to say I **don't** know what you mean. Would you have preferred a mere duplicate CV pointing to 'preposition stranding' (this topic has been done to death on ELU)? ELU seeks to address idiomaticity as well as clinical grammaticality (you can be perfectly grammatical and sound like an alien)? And this was ELU when we answered.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's not a matter of ELU or ELL. Since you seemed to be agreeing with JohnLawler all along, I thought you were on the same page with him regarding the use of 'colloquial'. But if you want to say, "all my comments are free of any mistakes", you're right. I don't want to put words into your mouth.